# How to define a function in pandas that takes series as an argument?

Tags: python, pandas, series, dataframe

I have a data frame and I want to create a new column whose values are defined by values located in other columns (in the same row). It is very simple if I use simple operations (`+`, `-`, `*` and even `abs`). For example:

```
df['new_col'] = abs(df['col1']*df['col2'] - df['col3'])
```

Then I defined my own function in Python and tried to do the following:

```
df['new_col'] = my_func(df['col1'], df['col2'], df['col3'], df['col4']).
```

Unfortunately it did not work. I think the reason why it didn't work is because `my_func` contains `asin`, `atan` and other functions that cannot be applied to series. For example, if I try `abs(df['col1'])` I get no complains, but if I try `asin(df['col1'])` I get an error message:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Is there a trick that will let me use `asin` (or my own function `my_func`) in the same way `abs` or `+` are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy`'s [universal functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html).

For your case, use [numpy.arcsin](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arcsin.html#numpy.arcsin) instead of `math.asin`.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like a good way to go. In my particular case I take values from different columns, compare them and use trigonometric functions. I read about universal functions on the site that you linked. There I can find universal functions for comparison as well as trigonometric functions. However, I do not see an universal if-function. Does such thing exist.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for ``some_series.where(condition, other_series)``.